# How to get triangles from 3D Delaunay triangulation

Tags: matlab, computational-geometry, triangulation

I've got a triangulation `dt` (or perhaps tetrahedralization) of a 3D point cloud and I'd like to find a nice way to extract the triangles from it. Note, I know how to get the tetrahedra, its simply `dt.ConnectivityList`, is there an efficient way to get the triangles from the tetrahedra? Every triangle should occur only once in the list.

Currently I'am doing the following - it is however painfully slow:

```
dt = delaunayTriangulation([X Y Z]);
tetrahedra = dt.ConnectivityList;

tris = cell(1, size(tetrahedra, 1)); % contains indices of tris in a tetra
for tt=1:size(tetrahedra, 1)
    vertIds = tetrahedra(tt, :); % vertex indices

    vmask = logical([0 1 1 1]);
    tris{tt} = [vertIds(circshift(vmask, [0 0 0 0]));
                vertIds(circshift(vmask, [1 1 1 1]));
                vertIds(circshift(vmask, [2 2 2 2]));
                vertIds(circshift(vmask, [3 3 3 3]))];
end

tris = unique(sort(cell2mat(tris'), 2), 'rows');
```

Comment: Noit that I had a look at any of the functions you used there, but did you try declaring `tris` as an array instead of a cell array? I've had "interesting" experiences with cells in large loops.

Comment: @McMa Yes, that's one possible optimisation, however, I will still need to sort each line and then remove dupes.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a vectorised version:

```
% take all four subsets of three points from the tets and concatenate
tris2 = [tetrahedra(:,[1 2 3]); tetrahedra(:,[1 2 4]); tetrahedra(:,[1 3 4]); tetrahedra(:, [2 3 4])];
% sort each row
tris2 = sort(tris2, 2);
% eliminate duplicates
tris2 = unique(tris2, 'rows');
```

With 100,000 test points (random numbers) I get

```
Cellmethod: time=9.870982, numelements = 1344960
Vectmethod: time=1.014797, numelements = 1344960
```

Comment: I'm aware it's probably far too late for your application but I liked the puzzle...